# Firestore Security Rules Request Parameters

Tags: angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

**In Firestore security rules, is there a way to access the parameters send as part of a list request?**

GOAL: I want to retrieve a `single` post-document that is `published`, by using its `slug` property.

QUERY:

```
let postDoc = this.afs.collection( 'posts', ref => ref
    .where( 'published', '==', true )
    .where( 'slug', '==', slug )
    .limit( 1 )
);
```

RULE:

```
allow list: if ( resource.data.published == true )
            && ( resource.data.slug == request.resource.data.slug )
            && request.query.limit <= 1;
```

PROBLEM: This results in 'no permission' error. However, if I remove `( resource.data.slug == request.resource.data.slug )` it works fine. I assume the problem is that `request.resource.data.slug` only exists for write requests, not for read requests (see https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rules/rules.firestore.Request).

**Is there a way to make this work?**

Comment: What do you mean by "request.resource.data.slug only exists for write queries"?  What's a "write query"?

Comment: What I mean is read rules apply to get and list, write rules apply to create, update, and delete. According to https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rules/rules.firestore.Request `resource` is present on write requests only. Hence it is not present on the list request I am using. So I am looking for a workaround to achieve this.

Comment: Good question, but do you need something like `( resource.data.slug == request.resource.data.slug )` ? How are you planning to use the `slug` field to restrict document access?

Comment: Basically, I want to ensure the request contains the `slug` field.

Comment: That's not something that's supported. It's the first time I've heard someone ask about this, so you might want to file a feature request. Can you accomplish what you need by using this in your `list` rule:
`resource.data.slug != null` With this, queries would have to include a where clause for `slug`.

Comment: @Ben I have to deal with the same problem. How did you solve it? Did Google do something?